# How to access an object's method from another object

Tags: java, netbeans, encapsulation

I have completed a small program for my Information System class that requires a java GUI to connect to a local database.  Everything is working as intended and I am able to insert/update, search, delete and send to printer as required by the instructions of the project. The project was completed in Netbeans btw.

Since I am done early I want to add some more functionality to the program.  For example when I hit the delete button in the GUI.  I don't want it to just say "entry not found" if there is no matching results or "entry successfully deleted" if an entry was indeed successfully deleted.

What I would like to do is have a message dialog box that asks "Really delete this entry?" (if an entry does exist) and two buttons: Yes/No.  If you press No then the message box closes leaving the original GUI but if Yes is clicked then the method that deletes the entry is called and the entry is deleted.

What I have done so far is:

```
mainClassThatStartsGUI(){

    //code
    deleteMethod(){
    //method to delete an entry  
    }


   //user wants to delete an entry and clicks the delete button.  Which in 
   //turn creates an object of the messageDialog class in order to display      
   //the message

   messageDialog gui = new messageDialog();
   gui.setVisible(true);
}

public class messageDialog(){

noBtn(){
//window just closes
}
yesBtn(){

 //wrong!

 mainClassThatStartsGui newObject = new mainClassThatStartsGui();

 newObject.deleteMethod();

}

}
```

So you can see my problem is I need the Yes btn to call the deleteMethod() of the main class in order to delete the entry but I can't do that because when I create an object to access that method it's a totally different object obviously.

I can't use simple getter/setter methods because I need to call the entire method not just simple textfield/textboxes for example.

Any help would be appreciated and please let me know if I'm not being specific enough or need more code.

Answer (score 0):

For your messageDialog add constructor variable of your main class and store reference to your mainClassThatStartsGUI as field. However i would call it as bad design — at least separate your "business logic", like deleteMethod into separate class.

Answer (score 0):

You `mainClassThatStartsGUI` should have a field of type `messageDialog`, this way each `mainClassThatStartsGUI` object has an object that supports `yesBtn` and `noBtn` functions. This is called Object composition.

Answer (score 0):

Illya and Sudheera thank you for the responses.  I haven't tried your solutions yet but I did find a simple way to solve my problem...I just made the deleteMethod() static.  My java professor would be so ashamed of me :(

Again thank you for your responses